# Can we get notification in the tab (change of title)?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, notifications, information-display, tabs

I'm usually running many different StackExchange sites in Firefox using tabs (using ReloadEvery to update every 5 minutes).  Right now to check for activity, I have to manually click on the tab to see if the envelope is lighted.

How about making the icon on the tab i.e. the title text change in some way, denoting that you have activity on the page?

We already add a message count for the chat tabs, so this shouldn't be very complicated.

Possible Example:

[image: Better Tab Bar]

Comment: @Lance, the first step is admitting that you have a problem.

Comment: @Popular, I don't think it's my problem, I think it's a problem with the Internet.  Please fix it.  (Adding chat didn't help me at all).

Comment: @Lance, I've heard of "someone on the Internet is __wrong__ " syndrome, but " __everyone__ on the Internet is wrong"?  Good luck with that, sir.

Comment: @Pop: *A* problem? Don't raise false hopes. He could stop at the first problem he finds ...

Comment: This would be a far more compelling feature request if the existing notification icon actually worked.

Comment: @Craig, valid point.

Comment: @Lance: Let me know if this reply triggers the script!

Comment: @The, that worked great!

Comment: I came here to create a question with this very request in it. +1

Comment: @LanceRoberts - Your imageshack link is broken.  Any chance you still have access to that?

Comment: Why do you need to check every tab? Use one consolidated account. The notification icon will show up on all sites with the same account.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, this was written before we had the type of functionality that we have today.  I now do it differently with usually two tabs open, but one would work.  And the way it's implemented today, they would all notify (and do, since I'm using Fosco's script, which isn't up to date, but kinda works ok).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Per an idea from Josh in chat, it could be done with a GreaseMonkey style script.

One has been built for this purpose at:  http://fosco.com/tab_notifier.user.js

Here's what it looks like (in Firefox):

[image]

**EDIT:**
New version for StackExchange Inbox:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           SE Tab Notifier
// @namespace      http://fosco.com
// @description    Update Tab Title when Inbox has content
// @include        http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include        http://superuser.com/*
// @include        http://serverfault.com/*
// @include        http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// ==/UserScript==


var script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = "(" + grease.toString() + ")()";
document.body.appendChild(script);

function grease()
{
 var notifyme = function ()
 {
       if ($('#portalLink a.unreadCount').is(':visible')) {
               var x = $(document).attr('title');
               var count = $('#portalLink a.unreadCount').text();
               var len = Math.floor(count/10);
               if (x.substring(0,len+2) != count + ' ') {
                       $(document).attr('title',count + ' ' + x);
               }
       }
 };
 window.setInterval(notifyme, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I don't think `@include http://*.com` will work...

Comment: You just have to change the include lines to be multiple includes of the form: `http://stackoverflow.com/*`.  I implemented it for all 5 urls, and took the parentheses off of the *.  I'll give you the bounty next week.  Thanks.

Comment: @Lance Editing to add a new version for the global inbox.

Comment: @Lance Updated link to new version.

Comment: very cool! consider listing this on stackapps http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/stack-apps-and-scripts/

Comment: @Jeff Thanks, and done: http://stackapps.com/questions/2362/a-user-script-to-update-the-page-tab-title-with-of-unread-notifications