# Any way to disable "question with new activity?"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, live-refresh

All it does is take up an additional line of space on top of the main page.  Yes, I know there's new activity, but I don't want to be notified of it.

Comment: Related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125199/does-the-x-questions-with-new-activity-feature-have-to-change-the-page-title

Comment: Apparently you just need to use my network admins.

Comment: Use IE9 [which does not support web sockets](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) :)