# Allow users to opt out of live-refresh

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, user-interface, live-refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to disable “question with new activity?”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125811/any-way-to-disable-question-with-new-activity)

Its really hard to use the site with the auto refresh.
Many times I'm reading a part in the middle of the page, and than the whole site jumps upstairs, and I'm loosing where I was.

I saw that many people here asked this feature, so my suggestion is- make a switch-button upstairs, and let the user define the desired action (auto refresh- yes/no), cause for whom who doesn't need the thread to get updated, and don't have any awareness regarding this, won't need & require this feature.

*I'm using Chrome 21.0.1155.2 dev-m. (OS: Win7Pro Sp1)*

**!EDIT!**

**Apparently this issue is a *Local Bug*, that I assume happening only to me**, as a result of some local extension, or anything else that I hope to discover.

This bug relates to my chrome version. It creates an unexpected behaviour in StackOverflow. The site gets Auto Refreshed instead of receiving live updates, the feature SO's dev team implemented lately.

***But*** still, if **users** want and **agree** with the idea **that StackOverflow needs** a ***live-refresh OptOut*** feature, **feel free** to upvote this question.

Comment: Its not a refresh, its an auto-update.  There is a big difference.  Beyond that I totally agree with you.  We should be able to opt-out of the live updates...

Comment: I have no idea man, but in my browser the site gets refreshed. (Chrome 21.0.1155.2 dev-m)

Comment: Well then you should use [a supported browser](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)... [so] does not have to support unstable and unfinished browsers

Comment: Chrome dev channel isn't?

Comment: No it isn't.​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: That's strange @NeoSwf because the live update works via websockets, which your browser supports. You mean to say the page is actually _refreshing_ and not just _updating_?

Comment: Yes.... Every few minutes. Like a page post.

Comment: @NeoSwf Then that's definitely a bug, but I don't think it's on the SE end (and bug reports are accepted only in the context of the last stable version of the browser). Could you update your question with the exact browser / OS details anyway? I'd love to see if I can reproduce this.

Comment: Additionally, if this bug is reproducible, you might want to [report it to **them**...](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry)

Comment: @Neo - IMO you should abandon the bug report (here at least since [so] does not support chrome's development channel) and focus on the feature request of opting out of the updates... [so] can't do anything about a bug in your browser... Report the bug to google... As a feature request I think this would be quite popular...

Comment: Thank you TimPost & Lix. Couldn't imagine that this issue relates to Chrome. I will modify my post.

Comment: @Lix- the thing is, if my browser did support Live-Updates, maybe it wouldn't bother me and I wouldn't report nothing here. Than I have no idea if I want to request that, cause maybe it's actually a good feature for the users, and there's no reason to invest in solving something that maybe don't need to be solved...

Comment: The fact is that [so] has no idea what your browser is capable of.  Your browser is still in development and as such might exhibit unexpected behavior.  The live-refresh is great although I think that one should be able to turn it off as it does sometimes obscure the information on the screen by moving it around...

Comment: @NeoSwf if you are saying that the page **actually refreshes** automatically, then AFAIK that is something we haven't seen before. We even don't auto-load content for the same reason - we just add a "this has been edited; click to reload" (different words) button. Are you seeing something different to this? Can you describe *exactly* what you are seeing?

Comment: You should probably update your question with the details of your problem, I don't think the upvotes understand you're not really talking about the (working) live updates

Comment: For info, I'm also watching in canary (21.0.1163.0), and it isn't misbehaving there

Comment: Firefox 7.0.1 on RHEL5 does not auto-refresh. You have to click the button to update it when it tells you there has been a new answer, edit, etc.

Comment: Than perhaps I got some plugin that interrupts everything... Got no idea. This problem happening to me only in SO. @MarcGravell - I believe that this thing is really local. StackOverflow is a developers website. Many of them using Canary & Dev channels. I was surprised that nobody complained about that before.

Comment: @MarcGravell- The description of my problem is simple - I cannot put the finger on the trigger, but sometimes it happens, & sometimes it don't. I started noticing this in the latest 2-3 weeks. I can read a page, and after a couple of minutes, the whole page reloads. I did see here, in Meta, the "*this has been edited; click to reload" button. but in SO I havn't...

Comment: @NeoSwf indeed, I have canary open on SO; it doesn't do what you describe. Perhaps the reason nobody has reported it is: it is local to you. So: do you have any particular plugins or user-scripts that might be candidates?

Comment: @BenBrocka - I have updated the question. I hope its much more clear now to users the reason I placed the question, and what it became to. Feel fee to edit it if you disagree with my editing.

Comment: @MarcGravell, the only I can think about is "Stackoverflow title alerter", but it doesn't make sense cause it modify only visual things that not relates to websockets. Besides that I have no other suspects. I will disable it or others, and return with news, when I'll have.

Comment: @MarcGravell- indeed its the "Stackoverflow title alerter". The Phenomenon stopped accruing.