# StackExchange activity in Firefox app tab

Tags: feature-request, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the X questions with new activity feature have to change the page title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125199/does-the-x-questions-with-new-activity-feature-have-to-change-the-page-title)

I have Stack Overflow currently pinned as an app tab in Firefox 10. The app tab has a nice feature that it changes color when the page has changed (for example, a new notification on Facebook will do that). I think it scans for some kind of DOM manipulation or something.

So far, the SO app changes color if new questions are posted. I don't think that is a good solution, as there can be dozens of new questions every hour and the vast majority of them is not interesting. What IS insteresting is another person's comment on your answer or a new answer to your question: that kind of info is shown on the StackExchange panel at the head of the page.

Can you modify it so that these activities trigger the Firefox notification (and not new questions)?

Comment: Why not just load up a [page that doesn't show questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/181070/jakub-zaverka), or filter questions by tags to only see what you are interested in?

Comment: I can do that, but still the activity is not recognized. I am much more interested in that than in new questions.

Comment: Oh, I see. It currently *doesn't* react to that. I (mistakenly) thought it does, but that you're request was that new questions cause excessively frequent notifications, and the notifications should be able to be limited to the StackExchange MultiCollider SuperDropdown