# Notifications in browser tab

Tags: feature-request, notifications

A very nice feature for *Stack Overflow* (and other *Stack Exchange* sites) would be to indicate the number of notifications (if any) in the browser tab like seen on Facebook:

[image: Facebook notification in browser tab]

Of course that would require automatic update if content has changed. Some kind of 'push-notification' which would be a nice feature as well.

Comment: That already happens when on the homepage/new questions lists and new questions come in. Can't see how your request can be accommodated... the one exception is Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Oded: For example, `(Q|I|N) Stack Overflow`, where `Q` is the number of new questions, `I` the number of inbox items and `N` the number of notifications.

Comment: Unless, @Oded, [Does the X questions with new activity feature have to change the page title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125199/does-the-x-questions-with-new-activity-feature-have-to-change-the-page-title) is implemented first :-)

Comment: @Arjan - You mean un-implemented ?

Comment: @Oded, yeah, well, if the feature request is implemented then the notification is un-implemented indeed.

Comment: I've up-voted this, because I agree it would be useful, but I will admit I hesitated. Only because there are so many other more important bugs / features to work on.

Comment: This would be great with [HTML5 Browser Push notifications](http://www.paulund.co.uk/html5-notifications)

Answer (score 9):

You might like the [StackAlert](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bpficcollblmkmoofnbnfhibdhfolamm) extension for Google Chrome, which does this in a little icon off to the edge of your screen:

[image]

Comment: Yes it's a good extension but it takes about 5 min before being notified... The SE inbox is instantly updated (using RSS feeds is even slower, at least to my experience). I hope they will make such features, it's really missing

Answer (score 1):

Per this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/57315/can-we-get-notification-in-the-tab-change-of-title), a user script was created to help draw attention to notifications even when the tab isn't in focus. It changes the page title to include the 'unreadCount' from the StackExchange SuperCollider.

[Here](https://stackapps.com/questions/2362/a-user-script-to-update-the-page-tab-title-with-of-unread-notifications) you can find the script.

I use tampermonkey to run the script as [recommended in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258989/manually-adding-a-userscript-to-google-chrome)