# Greasemonkey Script to Put Notification Indication in the Browser Tab

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, notifications, tabs, userscript

I find the number of questions that show up in the tab to be pretty useless.

What would be really useful, is if notifications of comments or badges or rep would indicate in the tab.

Since that is tangentially mentioned in other posts, **this post is a request for a Greasemonkey script that would put the notifications in the tab.**

Related Posts (for native functionality):

- [Show Inbox Updates in the Page Title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127139/show-inbox-updates-in-the-page-title)
- [Notifications in Browser Tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140151/notifications-in-browser-tab)
- [Personal Message Rep Change Indicator on SE Tab Page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268781/personal-message-rep-change-indicator-on-se-tab-page-title)
- [Inbox Notification Count In Tab Title Bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255247/inbox-notification-count-in-tab-title-bar)

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268781/personal-message-rep-change-indicator-on-se-tab-page-title) might be related IMHO.

Comment: A problem with this script is that these indications would show on _every_ tab. I find that hardly desirable.

Comment: @JanDvorak, what script?  Any script that does this?  There existed a script before the UI change that did exactly this, in just the SE tab, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Maybe [this script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2874/stack-alert-google-chrome-extension-keep-tabs-on-your-inbox-without-needing) will suit you? It is putting notifications not in the tab, but in the browser top bar, but it doesn't really matter, does it?

Comment: @nicael, tried it, didn't work.